# How can i extract html data with python?

Tags: python, html, extract

```
    <td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id1.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>link.here/python.php
                                </td>
                                <td>Linux</td>
<td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id2.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>link2.here/python.php
                            </td>
                            <td>Linux</td>
<td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id3.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>link3.here/python.php
                            </td>
                            <td>Linux</td>
```

here is an example of code and i want to extract the link on it using python can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: i've tried to resolve it using regex but this did not lead to a solution

Comment: I was just looking how to open an url and extract elements from the HTML DOM. I'm looking forward to some answer to your question! By the way, Do you already know how to open the url which gave you that HTML slice? Which library did you use if you don't mind my meddling? Ahh, by the way again: talking like a SO good citizien, Welcome to SO! Please visite our [tour] and read [mcve] in order to show us your effort! For more information look in the [help]. Otherwise your question would be low quality and incomplete, downvoted and possible closed. Good luck!

Comment: @EnderLook check out [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) + [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to to get data from websites. [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) is also a very good option. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

If all your links end with `php` you can do somthing like this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = '''<td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id1.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
...                                 <td></td>
...                                 <td>link.here/python.php
...                                 </td>
...                                 <td>Linux</td>
... <td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id2.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
...                             <td></td>
...                             <td>link2.here/python.php
...                             </td>
...                             <td>Linux</td>
... <td><img src="/images/cflags/png/id3.png" alt="Indonesia" title="Indonesia"></td>
...                             <td></td>
...                             <td>link3.here/python.php
...                             </td>
...                             <td>Linux</td>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
>>> [url.text.strip() for url in soup.find_all('td') if url.text.strip().endswith('php')]
['link.here/python.php', 'link2.here/python.php', 'link3.here/python.php']
```

Comment: this will work only with that html code i think ... if i add a complete html this will not work

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a sample of the actual html?

Comment: I have just edited my answer to (hopefully) cover your use case. If it is not enough please let me know. I find it easier to use a common substring to identify the links I'm interested into when performing this kind of task. Usually a domain or extension.

Comment: thank you very much for solving this ;) i've learned a new thing